# Get Set of row from mysql and generate dynamic range selector box using jquery in php and Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to generate a dynamic range selector or progress bar from 1 to 100 when page load. Initial value should be taken from database.

In below jquery #amount will hold the value of progress bar. #slider-range-min will be progress bar div tag. I want to generate this div tag dynamically when page load with t_id from database so my div tag id should be like this slide-range-min-1,slide-range-min-2 etc.

```
$(function() {
$( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
  range: "min",
  value: 0,
  min: 1,
  max: 100,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
  }
});
$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

Your HTML

```
 <div id="slider_1">
 </div>

 <div id="slider_2">
 </div>

 <div id="slider_3">
 </div>
```

And your js can be

```
$('div[id^="slider_"]').each(function(){
   id = $(this).attr('id');
   $(id).slider({
     range: "min",
     value: 0,
     min: 1,
     max: 100,
     slide: function( event, ui ) {
     // code here
  }
});
})
```

You can also make use of custom data attributes for each div to store initial DB values and give them to slider function